# "The reason I wear glasses is <so that> <so> I can see clearly."

Tags: optional-that

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reason-cause.3622889/post-18455630):
**(1)** *The reason I wear glasses is **so that** I can see clearly*.
my variant:
**(2)** *The reason I wear glasses is **so** I can see clearly*.

Is (2) correct?

Comment: With your exact context, ***that*** is optional, and it makes no difference whether you include it or not after ***so** = **in order** [that].*  Even without ***so***, it's optional, but I think we're much more likely to include it in, for example, *The reason I wear glasses is [that] I'm short-sighted.*

Comment: We can use **a finite clause** with **so that**.(The reason I wear glasses is so that I can see clearly) **In informal style** we can leave out **that**.(The reason I wear glasses is so I can see clearly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["so (that)" vs. "so"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177308/so-that-vs-so)